# Alternative for TextField with Multiple lines in Office ui fabric React

Tags: reactjs, spfx, office-fabric

I have used office ui-Fabric React controls on my form in spfx(react js framework).But I didn't find any textarea control in office ui fabric.

There is one column in my sharePoint list which is of type 'enhanced rich text(Multiple Lines of text)'. So while fetching the data from this field and showing it into my `<Textfield>` control, the data appears along with `<div>` tag.

So I am looking for some alternative in office ui fabric for a textarea field which can handle this enhanced rich text field data.

Currently I have used Textfield control with multiple lines.But it's a kind of plain text control.

```
<TextField multiline autoAdjustHeight value='Value here' name="textareaField" />
```

**Current Behaviour:**
It shows something like below in  control:

```
<div class='Ext66626FGSh'>Actual data here</div>
```

Expected Behaviour: The data retrieved from enhanced rich text field shoul appear in the control without any html tags.
Like only :

Actual data here

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [RichText](https://sharepoint.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/RichText/) Component from the [PnP SPFx Controls](https://sharepoint.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/) : it will parse SharePoint Rich Text Fields.